# Is there any unique key constraint on timestamps in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I'm sending some data to QuestDB and I'm curious if two records incoming that have the same timestamp will cause an issue / conflicts. Not even duplicate values, but values from different devices with the same timestamp. Any there any unique key constraint on new records with this type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of writing, there is no unique key constraint on timestamps, for a table with a designated timestamp, the only requirement is that it must be equal to or greater than the most recent timestamp value on the table.